# How many DataTable objects should I use in my C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, dataset

I'm an experienced programmer in a legacy (yet object oriented) development tool and making the switch to C#/.Net. I'm writing a small single user app using SQL server CE 3.5. I've read the conceptual DataSet and related doc and my code works.

Now I want to make sure that I'm doing it "right", get some feedback from experienced .Net/SQL Server coders, the kind you don't get from reading the doc.

I've noticed that I have code like this in a few places:

```
var myTableDataTable = new MyDataSet.MyTableDataTable();
myTableTableAdapter.Fill(MyTableDataTable);

... // other code
```

In a single user app, would you typically just do this once when the app starts, instantiate a DataTable object for each table and then store a ref to it so you ever just use that single object which is already filled with data? This way you would ever only read the data from the db once instead of potentially multiple times. Or is the overhead of this so small that it just doesn't matter (plus could be counterproductive with large tables)?

Comment: If you're moving to .NET I'd suggest skipping ADO and looking at Linq.

Comment: You mean I can use LINQ as the data provider for my whole app?

Comment: You can use LINQ to grab your data and bind against the results rather than using DataSets and TableAdapaters.  Its a much smoother workflow, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Will, I'm checking that out. I assume this is also the direction this type of code is going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CE, it's probably a non issue.  If you were pushing this app to thousands of users and they were all hitting a centralized DB, you might want to spend some time on optimization.  In a single-user instance DB like CE, unless you've got data that says you need to optimize, I wouldn't spend any time worrying about it.  Premature optimization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way to decide varys between 2 main few things
1. Is the data going to be accesses constantly
2. Is there a lot of data

If you are constanty using the data in the tables, then load them on first use.
If you only occasionally use the data, fill the table when you need it and then discard it.

For example, if you have 10 gui screens and only use myTableDataTable on 1 of them, read it in only on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

The choice really doesn't depend on C# itself. It comes down to a balance between:

1. How often do you use the data in your code?
2. Does the data ever change (and do you care if it does)?
3. What's the relative (time) cost of getting the data again, compared to everything else your code does?
4. How much value do you put on *performance*, versus *developer effort/time* (for this particular application)?

As a general rule: for production applications, where the data doesn't change often, I would probably create the DataTable once and then hold onto the reference as you mention. I would also consider putting the data in a typed collection/list/dictionary, instead of the generic DataTable class, if nothing else because it's easier to let the compiler catch my typing mistakes.

For a simple utility you run for yourself that "starts, does its thing and ends", it's probably not worth the effort.

You are asking about Windows CE. In that particular care, I would most likely do the query only once and hold onto the results. Mobile OSs have extra constraints in batteries and space that desktop software doesn't have. Basically, a mobile OS makes bullet #4 much more important.

Everytime you add another retrieval call from SQL, you make calls to external libraries more often, which means you are probably running longer, allocating and releasing more memory more often (which adds fragmentation), and possibly causing the database to be re-read from Flash memory. it's most likely a lot better to hold onto the data once you have it, assuming that you can (see bullet #2).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to figure out the answer to this question when you think about datasets as being a "session" of data.  You fill the datasets; you work with them; and then you put the data back or discard it when you're done.  So you need to ask questions like this:

1. **How current does the data need to be?**  Do you always need to have the very very latest, or will the database not change that frequently?
2. **What are you using the data for?**  If you're just using it for reports, then you can easily fill a dataset, run your report, then throw the dataset away, and next time just make a new one.  That'll give you more current data anyway.
3. **Just how much data are we talking about?**  You've said you're working with a relatively small dataset, so there's not a major memory impact if you load it all in memory and hold it there forever.

Since you say it's a single-user app without a lot of data, I think you're safe loading everything in at the beginning, using it in your datasets, and then updating on close.

The main thing you need to be concerned with in this scenario is: What if the app exits abnormally, due to a crash, power outage, etc.?  Will the user lose all his work?  But as it happens, datasets are extremely easy to serialize, so you can fairly easily implement a "save every so often" procedure to serialize the dataset contents to disk so the user won't lose a lot of work.